# STM32G4 CRC peripheral. What is going wrong in my configuration?

Tags: stm32, crc

I am trying to configure the CRC peripheral of my STM32G431C8T6 to work on 8-bit input values. The peripheral is calculating a checksum however if i compare the checksum it has calculated with the ones that online calculators calculate (such as [this one](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html)) it does not correspond. For example, I am configuring it with the following parameters:

1. Poly = 0x31
2. Initial value 0x00
3. No reversal of input data
4. No reversal of output data

When i then put in the test data 0xCC it gives me a checksum of 0x3a. However, according to online calculaters it should actually be 0x69.

This is the code with which i configure the CRC:

```
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_CRCEN;  // enable clock for CRC
CRC->POL = 0x00000031;     // set poly to 0x31 (1-wire)
CRC->CR = 0x00000010;       // configure crc to work on 8-bit input data
CRC->INIT = 0x00000000;     //init value
uint8_t test = 0xCC; // just a random number for testing
CRC -> CR |= 0x00000001; // reset the calculation
CRC -> DR = test; // put the test number in the data register
test = CRC -> DR; // read out result
```

Why am i getting 0x3a instead of 0x69? Is there something i am doing wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I solved the issue.** For anyone with the same problem, you need to write to the data register like this:  `*((volatile uint8_t *)&CRC->DR) = data;`

Instead of this: `CRC -> DR = data;`

Comment: Any idea why you need to do this?

Comment: Actually, now that I check my own code, I always use a Write_Reg macro when writing a value to registers rather than just going ->

Comment: Honestly i have no idea. I googled and found another stack question with the same problem and somewhere in the comments this was given as the solution.

Comment: @DKNguyen The `CRC->DR` is defined as a wider data type than `uint8_t`, and therefore the write access works differently. You can check this by using both variants and looking into the generated assembly.